# how to give interface for joi-objectid?

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

I am using joi to validate the schema of my objects. For objectid validation joi has a seperate package [joi-objectid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-objectid). I am using it for objectid validation. But recently when i am trying to migrate my code into typescript joi is throwing an error that objectid does not exist on joi. Since it is added at runtime we cannot get the reference. how can i override the joi types so that it supports objectid function.?

Comment: What about using joi.extends()? https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#extendextension

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to add it to the individual files.

```
import Joi from "joi";
import JoiObjectId from "joi-objectid";
const myJoiObjectId = JoiObjectId(Joi);

export const validateFixture = (input: object) => {
const schema = {
    home: myJoiObjectId().required(),
    away: myJoiObjectId().required(),
    date: Joi.date(),
    score: Joi.object(),
    stadium: Joi.string().required(),
    played: Joi.boolean()
  };

  return Joi.validate(input, schema);
};
```

Comment: This gave an error as there is no package @types/joi-objectid

Comment: You can check this out https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-objectid, instead of involking immediately, use a defined variable. Tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Joi has been updated. In the new version the `joi-objectid` does not work. :(
You can try this instead.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-oid

Answer (score 0):

```
import Joi from "joi";
import JoiObjectId from "joi-objectid";
const Joi.objectId = JoiObjectId(Joi);

const getDataById = (input: object) => {
  const validationSchema = {
    _id: Joi.objectId().required(),
  };

  const { error, value } = validationSchema.validate(input)

};
```